# How can I know what bluetooth stacks are installed in my cellphone and how to they works?

Tags: bluetooth

I want to send almost 4k size data to any cellphone by using bluetooth.

Firstly to do this, I need to find what stacks are in my phone and what stacks are acting when I send a data.

I really struggle to find the way; however, it is really hard.

If you know how to find it, please give me some information!!

Comment: What platform? J2ME? Windows Mobile? Blackberry? ...........

Answer (score 2):

See http://32feet.NET if you are talking about Windows Mobile.  It is a managed library for Bluetooth, OBEX, and IrDA.  We support both the Microsoft stack, but also have support for Widcomm.  And now also Bluesoleil and Stonestreet One Bluetopia.

You can either send and receive the data as an OBEX message, or over a simple bluetooth connection.  See a copy of the user's guide at http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/32feet.NET%20—%20User’s%20Guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Goto "https://www.bluetooth.org/tpg/listings.cfm" type the name of your mobile. This will give you information on the Bluetooth stack inside and the profiles supported.